# Put webcam flash inside divs

Tags: flash, html, webcam, swfobject

I'm trying to embed some flash code, and I'm using swfobject. When I put it in the parent div, it asks the users for permission on the webcam/audio. However, when I put the flash code into a lower-level div, it doesn't prompt for permission to use the webcam, or anyting. How do I fix this?

I.E.

I can put the flash into container, but not inside.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to update the reference id in the SWFObject JavaScript, or it won't know where you want your swf.